# Find strings listed in column into files and mark Yes or No in respective file name column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have strings listed in "A" column and file names are listed in column headers. I want to find whether string in "A" column exists in a file or not and add result in a file name column. I am hopeful that it is possible using vba.

I tried using formula "vlookup" (when added data into sheet) but it is time consuming calculation and as each file has 22K lines and for just 100 files all rows counts to 22 lakh lines. 
Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Table]

[image: Additional_Info]

Answer (score 0):

I got answer from this [site](https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/find-strings-listed-in-column-into-files-and-mark-yes-or-no-in-respective-file-name-column.35917/#post-215195). It's working as expected.

```
Sub Demo_StringSearch_txt()
Dim fPath As String: fPath = "C:\test\search\"
Dim strContent As String
Dim intFF As Integer: intFF = FreeFile()
Dim myArr
Dim i As Long, j As Long
myArr = Range("A1", Cells(Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Value

For i = 2 To UBound(myArr, 2)
    Open fPath & myArr(1, i) For Input As #intFF
    strContent = Input(LOF(intFF), intFF)
    Close #intFF
    For j = 2 To UBound(myArr)
        If InStr(strContent, myArr(j, 1)) > 0 Then
            myArr(j, i) = "Yes"
        End If
    Next
Next

Range("A1").Resize(UBound(myArr), UBound(myArr, 2)) = myArr


End Sub
```